# How to build and submit transactions in HyperLedger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In the context of HyperLedger Fabric I want to manually generate the private keys, then build and submit transactions. How can I do this?
I would like to do this in a very low level language, possibly C.

This is the analog of what I want in Sawtooth (in Python 3): https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0/_autogen/txn_submit_tutorial.html

Links and references are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Fabric transaction Flow : hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/txflow.html

This explains all the necessary steps in depth. In fabric, we always have to generate private keys manually (Either through cryptogen tool or using CA) and then use these keys to invoke and order a transaction. As of now, Fabric provides SDKs in Go,Node,JAVA and Python to accomplish t he flow you're asking. Python and Go could come close to the low-level-language like C/C++ from the all available options.